# how to install "dynaudnorm" audio filter for ffmpeg

Tags: audio, filter, ffmpeg

I am running linux Mint 17 64 bits-kernel 3.13-generic, with the  ffmpeg version:

> ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014

I need to run the 'Dynaudnorm' audio to compress audio files in a daily basis. But launching

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "in_original.wav" -af dynaudnorm "out_normalized.wav"
```

gives:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1efe820] No such filter: 'dynaudnorm'

The filter developer site explains that the integration in ffmpeg it's already done for the latest binaries, but in my version (update yesterday) doesn't show.

It's only Windows available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ffmpeg version is very old. Get a static build of the git build from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: I didn't know, i've got it from ffmpeg.org. 
I'll try it ASAP

Comment: P h e n o m e n a l.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

- Download the **ffmpeg** binaries from [zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds).
- Extract the archive file.
- Copy the contents of the `bin` folder to `System32`.

## Linux

On linux distributions use the terminal to download binaries!

I don't recommend to compile it yourself!

```bash
# On Fedora, use yum
sudo yum install -y

# On Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debain
sudo apt install ffmpeg -y # Or,
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg -y
```

> Or, manually compile it using the [CompilationGuide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).